# Network File Streaming Performance Vista

Tags: c++, windows, file, io

How can I achieve the best file streaming performance in Vista? My goal is to read a large file (several hundred MB) over the network directly into memory.

I've allocated a memory block the same size as the file. This is also my destination buffer. I've tried `ReadFile`, `_read`, `fread`, `ifstream::read`, and `boost::iostreams::mapped_file::const_data` -- specifying `_O_SEQUENTIAL` or `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` when appropriate. However, I haven't been able to match the throughput of a simple cut and paste file copy via Explorer. I routinely achieve only 50% of the performance of a file copy--profiled via Task Manager. What is Explorer doing differently, and how can I achieve the same level of performance?

Comment: It would help if you posted an example of your code.  It would be much easier for us to see what you're doing wrong.  You should easily be able to get performance at least as good as you get from Windows file sharing (which isn't particularly good).

Answer (score 0):

How bigs are the chunks that you read each time? if they are too small or too big then your not utilizing the network to its full capacity.

Comment: There's only 1 chunk. For example, I tried 400 MB file with a 400 MB destination buffer. How could the chunk be too large? If you're concerned about swapping, I have more than enough available physical memory to fit several chunks.